# Excel формула цикла

Tags: excel

Мне нужно рассчитать сумму оставшегося кредита через 12 месяцев.
Знаю как написать это кодом, но формулами - нет. Может кто знает?

```
var fullSum = 50000; // Изначальная сумма кредита
var perMonth = 1000; // Плачу каждый месяц
var pr = 0.005; // 0.5% в мес (6% годовых)
var month = 12; // плачу 12 месяцев

for(let i = 0; i < month; i++){
    fullSum = (fullSum-perMonth)*(1+pr);
}
// на выходе будет сумма, которую я должен буду через 12 месяцев
```

Comment: как-то вы мало информации дали

как выплата происходит? сколько берется с основного долга, а сколько с процентов? формулу можно на банковских сайтах поискать

Comment: Стоит посмотреть статью Николая Павлова [Расчет кредита в Excel](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/11/202/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For i = 0 To month-1
    fullSum = (fullSum-perMonth)*(1+pr)
Next i
```